# Need To Bulk Unchecked categories of products by CSV

Tags: csv, magento, categories, bulk-import

How can i Bulk Unchecked categories of products, Wrongly imported products with wrong categories of 100 products.  How can i  unchecked by csv.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity : check my question once again.

Comment: Are you asking me to check if it is now about programming? If so, It's not.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Do you know about magento.

Comment: Yes, and I know programming. You're trying to perform a CSV import - that's hardly programming. Can you please show the code that you're having trouble with? Perhaps that will help show the coding issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I am imported 100's of products to my site with wrong categories, so how can I unchecked selected categories by using CSV.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135560/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-enigmativity).